# Is there anyway to simulate a cell swipe so the cell swipes when the cell is tapped?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have been trying to find a solution for this, was wondering if there is anyway to simulate a cell swipe so when you tap the cell it will swipe to show its options (i.e. the delete one). I am actually using MSSwipeTable cell (https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell) and I like the animation effects, but I want this to work for tapping a cell not swiping. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method for that in `MGSwipeTableCell` : `-(void) showSwipe: (MGSwipeDirection) direction animated: (BOOL) animated;`

You just have to call it in your `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.

https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell/blob/master/MGSwipeTableCell/MGSwipeTableCell.h#L153

Comment: Great! thanks, I'll take a look and post back the result

Comment: do I have to declare the cell in the public interface? not sure how to access the cell object in (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath as it uses an NSIndexPath.

Comment: got it working! used: MGSwipeTableCell * cell2 = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; and then: [cell2 showSwipe:MGSwipeDirectionRightToLeft animated:YES]; Works great! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In Swift you can do the following:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
      let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MGSwipeTableCell
      cell.showSwipe(MGSwipeDirection.RightToLeft, animated: true)
}
```